# select and convert to comma separated array with jq

Tags: bash, jq

I have a json object in a bash script that looks like

```
obj={ "Obj": [ {"field1": a, "field2": true}, 
 {"field1": b, "field2": true},
 {"field1": c, "field2": false},
 {"field1": d, "field2": true}]}
```

I would like to filter it so that I get an array with items that have `field2` set to `true`
and then get its length (so in the example it would return 3 of the 4 items)

I tried

```
r=`echo $obj | jq '.Obj | select(.field2 == true)'`
r="[$r]"
echo $r
```

but this gives the elements without commas between them

```
[ {"field1": a, "field2": true} {"field1": b, "field2": true} {"field1": d, "field2": true}]
```

and I cant then use `jq length`

How do I get

```
 [ {"field1": a, "field2": true}, {"field1": b, "field2": true},{"field1": d, "field2": true}]
```

Comment: Please show your desired output in your question (no comment).

Comment: Please add output of `declare -p obj` to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 jq '.Obj | map(select(.field2 == true))' <<< "$obj"
```

You can then tack on a call to `length`, or perhaps you would consider something like:

```
.Obj | map(select(.field2 == true)) | ., length
```